# Server on Utilite pc

Tags: server

Just found Utilite PC (http://utilite-computer.com/web/home) saying they will run Ubuntu. I was wondering if this fanless PC will be strong enough to run a Ubuntu Server Distribution on it? Of course a small server - thinking of a small office server, running mail, calendar, a small internal webserver, etc.

What do you think?

Cheers Gerhard

Comment: you can run more than a server on that, that hardware is better than my laptop....

Answer (score 0):

There are several models, but yes, that's more than strong enough. Ubuntu Server is much more light-weight than an Ubuntu Desktop, since that's mostly what Ubuntu Server is – Ubuntu without a desktop. For a server like the one you describe, you could easily run Ubuntu desktop as well, and just add the services you want. At least the 4GB version.

Remember; Ubuntu is Ubuntu. There's nothing Ubuntu Server can do that Ubuntu Desktop can't and vice versa.